# XHR not suited for chat applications?

Tags: javascript, ajax

When we send an XMLHttpRequest, we always hundreds of extra bytes with it. In a normal usage it is good. But when building applications that needs speed, this is not good for reliablility.

```
function update(){
    var xhr = getXMLHttp(); // Normal catch handler for XHR
    xhr.open("POST", "update.php?r=" + "&chatvslog=" + user, true);
    xhr.send();
window.setTimeout("update();",300);
}
```

The request over does take all the way from 170 to 360ms to send. The problem is that I need this job done faster.

Is there a way of improving my XMLHttpRequest or doing this another way?

Comment: You're looking for Web Sockets.

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Comment: Check out BOSH - http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/technology-overview/bosh/

Comment: I'd say for most chats using anything XML-based adds unnecessary bloat. XMPP is nice, but overkill for a simple web chat. Especially one with anonymous users.

Comment: @SLaks Web Sockets cannot open PHP files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polling is a bad workaround that does the job in a small scalle but is not efficient and ugly to implement.

Modern browsers support WebSockets as a much better way to allow bidirectional communication. With something such as node.js' [Socket.IO](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io) you can even use a high-level WebSocket abstraction layer that falls back to whatever is available in the browser - it can use WebSockets (preferred) and techniques such as Flash sockets, AJAX long-polling or JSONp long-polling without you having to care about what's used.

Comment: How can I send basic HTTP requests without the XML?

Comment: Just because it's called XMLHttpRequest it doesn't mean XML needs to be involved.

Answer (score 0):

This is what WebSockets is designed for, but it's not yet supported on IE (though it's coming in IE 10), or some older but still-used versions of the other big browsers.

http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets

Until then, check out Comet:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)